# Impementing ads in android app

Tags: android

I developed an android app ,I want to implement ADS (e.g Google ads) in my app kindly let me know which ads provider is good and beneficiary among all and how to implement. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdMob is the popular and better ad network with banner ads,

this is the link [Admob sdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid) and sample code for integrating admob in your app

You can integrate Admob by using XML or by programatically.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know Startapp and Admob are better ad networks. These two are easy to integrate.
But startapp is profitable than Admob.

To Register and use StartApp [Click Here](http://www.startapp.com/)

To register and use Admob [Click Here](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/)